# Probabilities of independent events

Tags: probability

If you took six independent events, let's say football matches, each with unique probabilities of winning, what would be the probability of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or all of the football teams winning their games?

For example 6 football teams have probabilities of winning their respective games of: 66%, 72%, 58%, 91%, 55%, 85%.

Is there a formulaic approach to calculating the probability of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or six of the teams winning? Or is it only possible to calculate this using the very tedious method of multiplying all the different combinations of winning probabilities by the respective losing probabilities?

I have calculated this previously using the following method:

P(All Win) = 0.66*0.72*0.58*0.91*0.55*0.85 = 0.117 = 11.7%

P(1 Does Not Win) =

(1-0.66)*0.72*0.58*0.91*0.55*0.85 
+
0.66*(1-0.72)*0.58*0.91*0.55*0.85
+
0.66*0.72*(1-0.58)*0.91*0.55*0.85
+
0.66*0.72*0.58*(1-0.91)*0.55*0.85
+
0.66*0.72*0.58*0.91*(1-0.55)*0.85
+
0.66*0.72*0.58*0.91*0.55*(1-0.85)

= Something like 36% - I'm not typing all that in to my calculator.  But as you can see it's suddenly very tedious. And it gets far more tedious when trying to calculate the probability of exactly 3 teams winning their games.

Is there a cleaner formula that can calculate the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the probabilities off as the coefficients of

$$
(1+.66x)(1+.72x)(1+.58x)(1+.91x)(1+.55x)(1+.85x)\;,
$$

considered as a polynomial of $y$ with $x=y-1$. [Wolfram|Alpha gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B.66x%29%281%2B.72x%29%281%2B.58x%29%281%2B.91x%29%281%2B.55x%29%281%2B.85x%29%20where%20x%3Dy-1)

$$
.000242903 + .00556091 y + .0456643 y^2 + .174659 y^3 + .337485 y^4 + .319134 y^5 + .117254 y^6\;.
$$

Comment: If you want to understand the concept behind this, look up a topic called generating functions, which are simply power series in which the coefficients are the terms of a sequence. They are powerful here because with the help of computers, you can easily pump out all of these formulas and values simultaneously.

Comment: @CosmoVibe: Well, that's *one* reason they're powerful :-)

Comment: edited to be slightly more technical